# CoR pattern appropriate dependency Injection with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I was working on a suitable example of the CoR(Chain-of-responsibility) pattern. I learned that it is often used as middleware layer in MVC.

I am trying to write a middleware layer suitable for the pattern.

I have set my scenario regarding the implementation of the pattern as follows: The classes defined in the controller method as Annotations are linked to each other with chains, and each class performs a task and moves on to the next task. CoR(Chain-of-responsibility) pattern implementation known so far.

When I look at the examples, none of the classes used as middleware have been injected with Depency injection.

My scenario is as follows: An "@Middleware()" annonation is defined to the Controller method. Sample

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="test")
 * @Middleware({"App\Middleware\MiddlewareOne","App\Middleware\MiddlewareTwo"})
 */
public function test()
```

Then I get annotations in the "onKernelController" method with ControllerListener and create the classes defined here with a foreach loop and connect them to each other.

Below you will see the sample code blocks, respectively.

The problem I'm having here is How can I give the ContainerInterface or a Service class that I created in the constructor of the MiddlewareOne class to the constructor of this object?(I do not know which services are coming, a fixed service is not coming)

```
class ControllerListener
{
    /**
    * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ControllerEvent $controllerEvent
    */
    public function onKernelController(ControllerEvent $controllerEvent)
    {

        MiddlewareManager::handle($controllerEvent);
    }

}
```

---

```
class MiddlewareManager
{


   public static function handle(ControllerEvent $controllerEvent)
   {
       $containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
       if (!is_array($controllers = $controllerEvent->getController())) {
            return;
       }

       $reader = new AnnotationReader();
       $request = $controllerEvent->getRequest();
       $content = $request->getContent();

       [ $controller, $methodName ] = $controllers;
       $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($controller);
       $classAnnotation = $reader
              ->getClassAnnotation($reflectionClass, Middleware::class);
       $reflectionObject = new \ReflectionObject($controller);
       $reflectionMethod = $reflectionObject->getMethod($methodName);
       $methodAnnotation = $reader
            ->getMethodAnnotation($reflectionMethod, Middleware::class);

       if (!($classAnnotation || $methodAnnotation)) {
            return;
       }
       $middlewareList = $classAnnotation->getMiddleware()['value'];
                
        $middleware = null;
        $temp = null;
        foreach ($middlewareList as $class){
            if ($middleware === null){
                $middleware = new $class();
                $temp = $middleware;
                continue;
            }
            $class = new $class();
            $temp->next($class);
            $temp = $class;
        }
        return $middleware;
    
    }


}
```

---

```
class DumpOneMiddleware implements Middleware
{

  /** @var \App\Middleware\Middleware */
  private $next;
  /** @var \App\Service\ExampleService */
  private $exampleService;

  public function __construct(ExampleService $exampleService)
  {
      $this->exampleService = $exampleService;
  }

   /**
   * @param \App\Middleware\Middleware $next
   * @return \App\Middleware\Middleware
   */
   public function next(Middleware $next)
   {
       $this->next = $next;
       return $next;
   }

   /**
   * @param \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request $request
   */
   public function handle(Request $request)
   {
    if (!$this->next) {
        return true;
    }
    return $this->next->handle($request);
  }
}
```

Here I can export Container object via ControllerListener (to all middleware classes). But if I want to add another service, how can I do it?

When I examined these and similar topics, I came to the conclusion that I should look at the strategy pattern and Compailer Pass issues. But these topics didn't help me much or I couldn't understand.

I would be very grateful if you could indicate the deficiencies or mistakes in the scenario I applied and show with an example how I can inject Dependecy into the objects I created dynamically.

Comment: There's a lot of code in there to parse. Is there a reason your middleware can't be made available to normal DI? You are manually calling `new $class` so you aren't able to (easily) participate in the default pipeline of things.

Comment: In fact, there is no particular reason for anything I do. A scenario and scenario that I just made up for my own personal development may be wrong. Basically what I want is for classes written in @Middleware annotations to work with DI. If you have any ideas on how I can achieve this, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I consider myself a very advanced developer, however I've always tried to avoid saying "middleware" personally because it is too vague. So sticking with Symfony nomenclature, you have services which are automatically auto wired as part of a default install. Do these service need information in their constructors, or can all info be gleamed when an instance method is called? Would custom events work better for you? I strongly recommend checking out [Symfony casts](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-bundle/events), btw, they are totally worth the price and Ryan is a great instructor

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I realized that this kind of structure is inappropriate for symfony.  Yes, events are especially easy to do what I'm going to do here.  It was just a "could it be done" experiment.

Comment: I don't know if I'd go so far as to say that your idea is inappropriate for Symfony. The big advantage of Symfony is that if you follow the recommend patterns, you can often write way less code because boilerplate stuff is taken care of for you. However, Symfony also tries very hard to not get in your way, so if you want to do something your own way, you almost always can. For instance, you could just stash something into global state or a static property maybe. If you can build a PoC in pure PHP, you can sometimes "Symfony-ize" it later

Comment: It is possible that [Service Locators](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_subscribers_locators.html) might help you out since you don't know specific services in advance.  But as already mentioned, you posted quite a bit of code along with quite a few buzz words so I only have a vague inkling of what you are trying to accomplish.  Consider making a working example repository and posting over on the Symfony Reddit board.  Might be a better fit.  There are also PSR Middleware standards.